# Terminal emulator with shortcut to switch to latest tab

Tags: 19.10

Is there a terminal emulator with a shortcut to "latest tab"? I've tried GNONE Terminal, Tillix, Guake, Terminator, Tilda, and others, to no avail.

The shortcut Ctrl-PageUp should map to previous tab, but for me it always goes to the tab on the left.

Im looking for functionality like Alt-Tab to change between applications, or Ctrl-Tab to switch between tabs in last used order, in Firefox.

Comment: You can change shortcuts from Edit > Preferences of Terminal software, by default it's set Ctrl+Page Up/Down and not available to set Ctrl+Tab perhaps it's a global shortcut, I could set Ctrl+1 for the Next Terminal.

Comment: Tab  key can be used for some reason. It's a documented bug. Previous/Next behave as the Tabs to the Left/Right. It's not ordered by 'last used'.